# How to plot a vertical line with fixed range in grid?

Tags: plotting, graphics

I want to plot a vertical line on a graph. The plot range on the graph ranges from 0 - 12. I want the vertical line at x-axis = 0.8, but the vertical height going from 0 to 7 only. I am not sure how to do this. I tried with gridlines but there seems no easy way around that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the option [`Epilog`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Epilog.html) or [`Prolog`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Prolog.html) to add graphics primitives (lines, points, texts, etc.) to your plot:

```
Plot[2 Pi + 2 Pi x Sin[6 Pi x], {x, 0, 1},  
 Epilog -> {Red, Line[{{.8, 0}, {.8, 7}}]}]
```

[image]

```
Plot[2 Pi + 2 Pi x Sin[6 Pi x], {x, 0, 1},  
 Prolog -> {Red, Line[{{.8, 0}, {.8, 7}}]}]
```

> same picture